# Adding TabItem from another User Control

Tags: c#, wpf, class

I am stuck in a very basic thing.

There are two user controls on a shell window. First one basically have a ribbon control. Second control basically has a tab control.

How can I add a new tab item when a button clicked on the ribbon? All the views including Shell share the same namespace.

In **Ribbon.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Name="RibbonControl" ... >
```

In **WorkSpace.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Name="WorkSpaceControl" ... >
```

In **Shell.xaml**

```
<RibbonWindow  x:Name="ShellWindow" ... >
    ...
    <Views:RibbonRegion x:Name="RibbonControl" />
    <Views:WorkspaceRegion  x:Name="WorkSpaceControl" />
    ...
</RibbonWindow>
```

In **Ribbon.xaml.cs**

```
namespace Application.Views
{
  public partial class RibbonControl: UserControl
   {

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        //This throws the error that name is not available in current context.
        WorkSpaceControl.AddDataTab("Hede");   


        //This doesn't throw error. But I think because the tab control
        //has already initialized, it doesn't add the tab neither.
        TabRegion su = new TabRegion();
        su.AddDataTab("Hede");

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have a look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968367/wpf-c-sharp-programatically-adding-and-moving-tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a good sleep, here is the answer:

```
Shell MainFrm = (Shell)App.Current.MainWindow;
MainFrm.WorkSpaceControl.AddDataTab("Something");
```