# Adding Tabitems dynamically with Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Im new to WPF and im trying to add tabs to my TabControl. The LoadTable Function returns a DataTable which contains the Information and should be represented to the DataGrid for every Tab.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= number_MaxSemester; i++)
{
     TabItem item = new TabItem();

      // Name of TabItem
      item.Header = i + ". Semester";

      //Contains the Data from Database
      item.DataContext = loadTable();

      Tabs.Items.Add(item);
}
```

loadTable Function which returns the Datatable

```
    public DataTable loadTable()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            //Open Connection to Database
            using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(cs))
            {
                //Command string for the Sqlite Command
                string query = "SELECT Fach, Note, Statusfach, Versuch from infostudent WHERE username = + '" + UserName.Content + "'";

                SQLiteDataAdapter dbAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(query, con);


                //Fill Data with SQLite Data
                dbAdapter.Fill(dt);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        return dt;
    }
```

Here is the XAML Code:

```
<TabControl x:Name="Tabs" Margin="10,61,0,57" Width="584" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataGrid />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    </TabControl>
```

Comment: So, what is your question exactly? I don't see any. Since it is your first question, please read [FAQ] and [ask] as a start..

Comment: @SonerGönül the Data in the DataGrid isnt showing. Look up ive added the Question

Comment: Have you checked this link [WPF C# Programatically adding and moving tabs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968367/wpf-c-sharp-programatically-adding-and-moving-tabs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the **Content** property of the TabItem to your DataTable:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= number_MaxSemester; i++)
{
  TabItem item = new TabItem();

  // Name of TabItem
  item.Header = i + ". Semester";

  //Contains the Data from Database
  item.Content = loadTable();

  Tabs.Items.Add(item);
}
```

...and bind the ItemsSource property of the DataGrid to the DefaultView of the DataTable in the **Content**Template of the TabControl:

```
<TabControl x:Name="Tabs">
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DefaultView}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: thank you so much! its working now! The Binding was the problem